# TextBox with an Error bob

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to have a textbox which always displays an Error Bob next to it. For that I wrote the below code:

```
<TextBox Text="My TextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="75" Width="75">
    <TextBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <DockPanel>
                <Image..."error bob image is added here"/>
                <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1.2"/>
            </DockPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </TextBox.Template>
</TextBox>
```

I am able to see the same in the designer. However when I run this solution, I see only a textbox with a red border. The image (i.e., the error bob) is not visible. Can anyone suggest why this happens?

Comment: You might want to set `DockPanel.Dock` property on `Image` and `Border` elements. Also, set `LastChildFill` property to false on `DockPanel` element.

Comment: I did try the below, however still unsuccessful.                        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
<Image Source....DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
I am able to see what I want in the designer. However when I run the application, the same doesn't get projected.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set property `LastChildFill="True"` of `DockPanel`:

```
<TextBox Text="My TextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="75" Width="75">
    <TextBox.Template>
       <ControlTemplate>
          <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                    <TextBox BorderThickness="0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="error bob image is added here" Width="100"/>
                    <!--<Image..."error bob image is added here"/>-->
                   <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1.2"/>
                </DockPanel>
       </ControlTemplate>
   </TextBox.Template>
</TextBox>
```

You can use `TextBlock` with `Width` instead of `Image` to show your text "error bob".

**Update:**
I double checked and it works. Please, see the following image:

[image]

In addition, you can use `StackPanel`, if it is okay:

```
<TextBox Text="My TextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="75" Width="275">
  <TextBox.Template>
     <ControlTemplate>
       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <TextBox BorderThickness="0"/>
          <TextBlock Text="error bob image is added here" Width="100"/>                        
          <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1.2"/>
       </StackPanel>
     </ControlTemplate>
  </TextBox.Template>
</TextBox>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response.As mentioned above, I did set the property LastChildFill to "True", Still no luck!

Comment: Tried. Still no luck :(

Comment: yep, stackpanel->better than dock